# Bring in custom NSF as data service to Bluemix

Tags: xpages, ibm-cloud

I would like to bring a custom NSF for data service in Bluemix. I can create a copy of the NSF to the Bluemix server, but from there I can not bind the service to my XPages application since it does nowhere appear under available services.

The reason why I have created a copy of the NSF file to Bluemix is that I want to avoid the default todo_data.nsf file name. This filename gives the customer the indication the application is not ready/finished and it does not reply to my application which is not a todo application.

Are there other ways to provide a NSF data service with a custom filename?

Answer (score 1):

In the bluemixContext there is a utility method to facilitate what you are describing. It was added in release 15 of the ExtLib. You can see the code here: https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/blob/master/extlib/lwp/product/runtime/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.bluemix.util/src/com/ibm/xsp/bluemix/util/context/DataService.java#L132

Once your custom data NSF is copied up to the XPages NoSQL Database service, you should be able to reference it inside your design NSF as follows:

```
bluemixContext.getDataService().findDatabaseByName("customDbPath")
```

Pass that value to the databaseName property of your XPages data sources, like how the boilerplate example app does it for tododata.nsf using `findDatabaseName()` instead.

Comment: when i try bluemixContext.isRunningOnBluemix()? bluemixContext.getDataService().findDatabaseName('Bildr52_Data.nsf') : '' I get the error message Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=53: Error calling method 'getDataService()' on java class 'com.ibm.xsp.bluemix.util.context.BluemixContext'
No data services found.

Comment: Is there a data service bound to the XPages bluemix app?

Comment: no. the custom nsf does not emerge as available data service. therefor the indistinctness.

Comment: So are you pushing the data nsf up with the front-end NSF to Bluemix?? This would not be recommended.

Comment: no i am not saying that. I am saying that I pushed the data nsf via the Notes client to Bluemix and the design via the deployment toolbar via Domino Designer

Comment: "I pushed the data nsf via the Notes client to Bluemix" - where do you mean exactly? "Bluemix" is vague

Comment: I pushed the data NSF to the Domino server (lagan/Bluemix) on Bluemix in my data folder (bluemix/my_mailid_domain_com/organization/custom.nsf). May I conclude that uploading custom nsf's to that directory disturb the functioning of the applications? As soon as I remove my custom nsf's I had working apps again.

Comment: You should be able to push custom NSFs to that directory. Then if an XPages data service instance is bound to the application, you should be able to use the method I suggested, but you'll have to specify the sub-folder I suspect `bluemixContext.getDataService().findDatabaseByName("subfolder/customDbPath")`